# How to convert image to Base64 and include in Json as result

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

newBie in asp.net WebApi.

1) How to resize an image and convert it to base64 and return it to Client.

2) I am not sure about the pro and con on base64 conversion vs byteArray for image.

3) Which format is better to use in webApi 
   return image in byteArray or Base64 in json.

understand these are allowable dataType. So, sending image bytes is not ok.
    In JSON, values must be one of the following data types:

```
    a string
    a number
    an object (JSON object)
    an array
    a boolean
    null
```

I need fast processing for webApi.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **atob** to ***base64 decode*** and use **btoa to encode**

> you need to **Escape datas** **before to encode base64**

```js
    function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str )));
    }

    function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
      return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob( str )));
    }

    // Usage:
    var test1 = utf8_to_b64('✓ à la mode'); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="
    var test2 = b64_to_utf8('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='); // "✓ à la mode"
    
    console.log(test1);
    console.log(test2)
```

base more complet for more type of data https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/Add-ons/Code_snippets/StringView

Comment: I am not using WebBrowser or Asp.net MVC web app. I need to use C# and netframework to handle in WebApi and return result as Json.

Comment: Sorry i guess i see javascript stockoverflow show me as a question of my filter i dunno why :(.